# Creating <div> grid with JQuery for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm new to web development but have a pretty solid programming background. I've tried multiple ways to create a  element programatically based on user input. I'm trying to essentially create a grid through JQuery.

I'm tackling this problem by storing the user input into a variable and going through a for loop to create the grid. Here is the code for the .js file:

```
var rows = 8;
var columns = 8;
var $row = $("<div />", {class: 'row'});
var $square = $("<div />", {class: 'square'});

$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){      
            $("#wrapper").append($row);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < columns; i++){
            $(".row").append($square);
    }
});
```

Now for some reason, this code only creates one row in #wrapper and one square in the row. I've tried copying the example CSS files that tackle this problem but nothing seems to work. Here's what I have right now for my CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 850px;
    height: 850px;

    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    background: #000000;
}

.row {
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;

    background: #313131;
}

.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    margin: 0px;

    outline: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Draw Grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" >
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="draw.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anybody help me out? I'm so confused. I've tried everything. Is this a CSS formatting error?

Comment: Put the actual DOM code e.g. `$('<div />', {class: 'row'})` in place of `$row`. $row is probably representing a single instance and thus gets appended to each place, each time rather than creating a new instance each time.

Comment: Also, creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L0e6mxcp/) of your problem will often help to get you answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are creating only one row and square objects, you need to use cloned copies else they are just copy

```
var rows = 8;
var columns = 8;
var $row = $("<div />", {
    class: 'row'
});
var $square = $("<div />", {
    class: 'square'
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    //add columns to the the temp row object
    for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        $row.append($square.clone());
    }
    //clone the temp row object with the columns to the wrapper
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        $("#wrapper").append($row.clone());
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ffxjkq2p/)