# Javascript - Trying to create a grid, but can only get rows. I am not sure what to do next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I am trying to create a etch-a-sketch and I need to generate multiple divs (i.e. little squares) based on the users input. So for instance the option is how many pixels do you want the grid size to be from 1 - 50 and based on the answer (say 30) I need to make a grid with that many squares on each side. The issue is that I can only get that many squares as a row at the top and not as a grid. Linked is my code and also shown is my javascript code which is the one giving me issues. The HTML/CSS are mostly just styling, but they are shown in the link. I am not sure what I am doing wrong because I am using someone else's code as reference and it seems to work for them, but not for me.

https://codepen.io/faar23/pen/qjZgQY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/*for (var i = 0; i < 24; i ++) {
  $('#workspace').append('<div class = "row"></div>');
  $('.row').height(27);
 };*/
  /*for now i am going to leave the above code commented out but what it 
does is instantly creates 24 boxes on the workspace
  and without this, the space is empty. I am commenting it out to see if the 
.height function will wor down below...doesnt seem to*/

/*the above loop generates 24 divs dynamically without having to copy paste 
in html. the .height sets the height of the divs.
the width is set in the css under myId. this was done using this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtgx_twX-a4 + inspecting
the elements on this project https://beachfern.github.io/sketchpad/*/

$('#mainButton').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#mainButton').addClass('highlight');
});

$('#mainButton').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#mainButton').removeClass('highlight');
});

/*the above code makes the main start button change color when the mouse 
enters it*/

$('.buttonhide').hide();

$('#mainButton').click(function(){
    $('.buttonhide').show();
});

/*the above code hides the rest of the buttons until the main button is  
clicked, then all the buttons show themselves*/

$('#mainButton').on('click', function(){
  var workspaceSize = prompt("How many boxes should make up the canvas? (1 
to 50)", "24");
  /*i am going to use this user's way and see if that works better for me 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518243/creating-div-grid-with-
jquery-for-loop*/
  if(workspaceSize > 0 && workspaceSize <= 50){
  $('#workspace').empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < workspaceSize; i++){
    $('#workspace').append('<div class = "row"></div>');
  };
  for (var x = 0; x < workspaceSize; x++){
    $('.row').append('<div class = "column"></div>');
};
      $('.row').height(700 / workspaceSize);
      $('.column').height(700 / workspaceSize);
      $('.column').width(700 / workspaceSize);
    }; /*very imp closing bracket. shit doesnt work without it*/
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest the two for loops, so that for each row it creates the columns.

This might work, or lead you in the right direction:

```
for(var i = 0; i < workspaceSize; i++){
  $('#workspace').append('<div class="row" id=row'+i+'></div>');
  for(var j = 0; j < workspaceSize; j++){
    $('#row'+i).append('<div class="column"></div>')
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything at all. I am having the same issue as before, only the first row displays based on the number chosen. Any other ideas?

Comment: I saw that you did not have a class called column in the css, I added it and then it did show up. You could try that, let me try to recreate the jsfiddle

Comment: This one seems to work https://codepen.io/bapauw/pen/VWjXPg, ignore the missing column class though.